# How to view SQLite database which is present in bluestacks ?

Tags: android, sqlite, bluestacks

Hi I am using Blue Stacks in Debuggable mode with eclipse to run mt development build.
On checking Data in file explorer of DDMS tab i cannot goto database in blue stacks? Any tips?

Comment: No you can't see DB in BlueStcks but you Export this Programmatically.

Comment: one more thing, i connected my android mobile phone and checked, but still the same result

Comment: and after some googling i found an emulator called genymotion, almost functions likes bluestacks and we can view its database via data/data/package/databases cool, i shifted to geny now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
File f=new File("/data/data/YOURAPPPACKAGENAME/databases/YOURDATABASENAME");
                    FileInputStream fis=null;
                    FileOutputStream fos=null;

                    try
                    {
                      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                      fos=new FileOutputStream("YOURSDCARDFOLDERPATH"+"/YOUREXPORTDDATBASENAME");
                      while(true)
                      {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                      }
                      fos.flush();
                      Toast.makeText(context, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(context, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception ioe)
                      {}
                    }
```

And add `permission` into your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You must add sdcard read and write permission into your manifest.xml file and after database successfully exported open using SQLite Manager.

Comment: @user3244439 now you got DB into your specify path

Comment: but how to pull and push db files using bluestack?